# Social Media Feather icons not displaying for each post

Tags: social-sharing

I'm using the following code to display the "Social Media Feather" widget for each post, but icons are only displayed for the first post and not the rest:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged' )) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged
);              
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();   
    $count=0;
    ?>
    <div class="row event-list  my-events <?php echo $type[0]->name; ?> ">            
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 paddingdel-l">
            <h5><?php the_title( ); ?></h5>
            <div class="row">                             
                <div class="co-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 event-list-right">                          
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 paddingdel-l pad0">
                        <img src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>/share.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 social">                     
                        <?php get_sidebar('share'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                   
        </div>                
    </div>    
    <?php 
endwhile; endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did it with shortcode. Instead of using `<?php get_sidebar('share'); ?>` used `<?php echo do_shortcode('[feather_share]' ); ?>` for sharing icons .I guess a widget can only be displayed for one time on a page